# LOCATION_CHANGING event not getting dispatched when location of htmlLoader is changed

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe

I want to do my stuff on LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE event which is introduced in AIR 2.7 but this event is not getting dispatched.My sample code is below. Please help me know if there is anything wrong that I am doing.

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
  this.page.location = "http://www.google.co.in";
}

protected function locationChanging(event:LocationChangeEvent):void {
 trace("location Changing");
}

protected function page_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                  this.page.htmlLoader.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, locationChanging, false, 10, false);
}
<mx:HTML id="page" width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete="page_creationCompleteHandler(event)"/>
```

Comment: By definition, locationChanging event is dispatched when the location change is initiated through user interaction. I am clicking the links on the loaded page but event is not getting dispatched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why locationChanging event was not dispatching. I did few things to make it work.

1. I upgraded my flex sdk from Flex 4.1 to Flex 4.5
2. Added compiler option -swf-version=12
3. Overlayed AIR 2.7 sdk over Flex 4.5 sdk